# Complex object with httppostedfilebase wont bind uppon submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi im having a problem with my complex object, here is my model

```
public class screen{
      public dictionaryscreen currentvalue {get; set;}
      public dictionaryscreen newvalue {get;set;}
}

public class dictionaryscreen{
      public string name {get; set;}
      public HttpPostedFileBase imagefile {get;set;}
}
```

And here is my method:

```
public ActionResult Submit(screen model){
     [Some logic....]
}
```

And lastly my view

```
@model project.Models.screen

@using(Html.BeginForms())
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newvalue.name)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newvalue.imagefile , new { type = "file"})
}
```

Upon submission the model has the value of name but the file got null. What can i do to get the file with this kind of model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using plane @using(Html.BeginForms()) Try to use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

Comment: Yes, i notice that. Thank you